# Making a tkinter window with dynamic Label that contains no buttons

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple timer kind of GUI application using the python tkinter module.
The requirements of my application are

1. Should have no buttons.
2. It must have a dynamic field that shows the time taken in seconds.

I have searched a lot but wasn't able to conclude.

So, expecting whether can my requirement be met using Tkinter?
If yes, wishing to know the way of achieving it.
If no, can my requirement be met using any other python or other GUI libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a yes or no Q? Yes your requirements can be met using tkinter

Comment: If yes, i'm looking to know the way of achieving it

Comment: Show us what you've done so far, so we can correct it

Comment: Sorry man, I'm actually building a web automation project, that would notify me when my requirement is met in web. I chanced my question in a diffrent way as I din't wish to disclose my complete project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved with tkinter, take a look at this example below:

```
from tkinter import * #importing
import time

root = Tk() #creating a window

def change():
    l.config(text=time.ctime()) #update the text on the label
    root.after(500,change) #repeat the function each 500 ms

l = Label(root, text='Hello world',font=(0,20)) #creating a label on window
l.pack() #putting it on the window

change() #calling the function initially

root.mainloop() #putting it inside a loop
```

Note that your calling this function each second, which might not be efficient, this is will work for small projects and its here to just give you an idea.

Hopefully you get a idea of whats going on here, I recommend you watch a detailed video on tkinter and proceed to work with it.